# How to installed ubuntu 12.04 lts alongside windows 7?

Tags: video, pdf

.
I am using windows 7 64 bit and want to install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS alongside windows 7

Please tell me how I can do that.

Comment: just follow the live cd. if you can read you can't get it wrong...

Answer (score 0):

So easy!

1. Install Windows 7, 64 Bit, don't use the entire hard disk let us say from 500GB, make a new partition with the win7 installer's partition manager and choose the 250GB partition and install. Let the rest of it untouched, that will handle linux!
2. After installation of Windows7 had been done, take the ubuntu cd inside, make sure you have internet connectivity (best through router via DHCP) and put the linux cd inside.
3. Ubuntu will ask you questions like keyboard, language and at the certain point ubuntu will ask you to start the installation "default".

   I personally advise making the partition myself.

   On a standard system (without EFI) you have 4 primary partitions... Windows reserved one primary partition so you still have 3 left.
4. create one primary partition for /boot with 1 GB, and one more for virtual partition.

   Inside the virtual partition, you create partitions for linux folders!

   Most imporant are:

   /tmp (5GB)
   /opt (50GB)
   /usr/local (10 GB)
   /home (20GB)
   swap partition (doube the memory, but 8GB would do it fine, and more is not necessary)
   / (the rest of space -> 250 - 93 = 157GB)

   during the installation ubuntu will fetch the packages too.
   After the installation had been done, ubuntu writes the boot manager with grub    automaticly so that you can choose between win and linux which system you like to boot.

Does it have to be 12.04 ?! Take the latest xubuntu (http://xubuntu.org/), then you don't have to mess with the ressources hungry Gnome3 UI, which was not the case with Gnome2

But of course, it's up to you.....

Have fun!